# Full Screen Background Image Stops Scaling In Portrait

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm pulling my hair out learning RWD.

http://www.blinkbysecretlashes.co.uk/?ModPagespeed=off

This clients holding page looks okay in landscape but all the portrait versions chop off the models face instead of scaling the image down. Unfortunately the logo is part of the main image and I can't get it separately.

I don't understand why the image seems to scale nicely until it gets to about 800 pixels wide then starts cropping instead. I can't see anything in the (simple) CSS that would cause this. Unless is something bootstrap does that I don't fully understand yet?

Comment: Instead of 'left top' try 'center top'. That what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Billy- I've tried that thought it still starts cropping at viewport sizes less than about 800 pixels. V annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your site, and I see the expected behavior. You told the browser to cover all available space with a background image. When a browser can no longer cover the entire space, i.e. it hits a limit on one dimension, it has no choice but to start cropping the other dimension to keep the aspect ratio constant. After all, you don't want distort this model's face.

Try, for example, to replace

```
background-size: cover;
```

with

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

and you will see what I mean.

EDIT:

If you want to use the same image, try this:

```
background-position: center top;
```

Now your image works very well for portrait too.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I think I'm wrapping my head around this now :) Would the a good approach to therefore have smaller images or 'portrait friendly' images that I switch to those smaller viewport sizes?

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I did that and changed the background-size to contain on the portrait sizes and its looking good (finally!)